# How to find the last A that the rest string contains the first B in RegEx?

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a large number of files to be renamed, which the names contain chaos postfix. I am using some advanced rename software, and wonder how to write a RegEx that to remove the postfix. Some examples are:

```
Content - Still content-A pOst fix
Content-- BpOst - fix with - inside (dashes in postfix)
Content-Still --Content  -CpOstfix (dashes in content)
Content fake pOst - real pOst --fix (two keywords, one in content and postfix each)
Content fake- pOst - real pOst --fix (two keywords both in postfix)
Content fake pOst fix (space is not a splitter of pOstfix, so nothing removed)
```

I want the output to remove all post fix including leading dash and/or spaces. The desired output is:

```
Content - Still content
Content
Content-Still --Content
Content fake pOst
Content fake
Content fake pOst fix (space is not a splitter of pOstfix, so nothing removed)
```

I don't even know if this is possible by RegEx.

Uncertain number of dashes (with or without space) are the splitter of post fix, but both content or post fix may contain dashes and/or fixes, but say, all post fix contain a certain letter(s) inside (e.g. letter `O` or `pOst` in this example).

There are some points:

1. The splitter between content and postfix is only dash(es), if there is only space, it is not splitter.
2. Dashes and spaces may included both in content and postfix, so I cannot simply search the first/last dash as the splitter - it is the last dash, including leading space(s), before the first occurrence of the certain letter(s) is found (see the last example).
3. I want to find a way of writing a single RegEx expression, rather than gradually remove the postfix.
4. The entire filename may have non-ASCII characters, especially `certain letter(s)`. So it's not ideal to use something like `[a-zA-Z]`.

PS: I also wonder how to character class that includes A but not B?

e.g., I want all alphanumeric, but exclude letter a and number 5, something like (obvious will not work): `/[\w^a5]+/`. Apart from writing an exhaustive list like `/[b-zA-Z0-46-9]/`, is there any better way? Like unions and intersections?

I sincerely appreciate with any help. Many thanks.

Comment: A regex by itself only *matches* (parts of) strings. What capability does this "advanced rename software" exactly have, is it able to *replace* regex matches by other content? Does it allow capturing groups? What regex implementation does it use? Linking (the docs) or at least naming the software would help.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. I use both Advanced Renamer on PC and A Better Finder Rename on Mac. What did you mean by capturing groups? What do you mean by the implementation of RegEx? Are there any different RegEx? Sorry, I am learning RegEx so not knowing much, and I rather not find alternatives to the task as I am also trying to improve my skills in RegEx. Thanks again.

Comment: You read http://www.advancedrenamer.com/user_guide/regular_expresions? If not, you really should do. It also contains exactly the info I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to replace

```
\s*-+\s*[^O-]*O.*$
```

with the empty string. It will match one or more dashes (surrounded by optional whitespaces), followed by at least one `O` before the end of the input.

If you want to match a whole phrase, you would need to use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like this:

```
\s*-+\s*((?!pOst)[^-])*pOst.*$
```

Comment: Thanks. And also thanks for your link in comment. However, I tried your expression, it's not working :(

Comment: Thanks, this works much better. But still a small correction: `\s*-+\s*[^O-]*O.*$`, otherwise it will always start from the first `-`. PS, how to modify it to match `pOst` instead `O`?

Comment: @TideGu: Thanks, I missed that as well… Updated the answer.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!